# How to write an integral under a dot derivative?

Tags: math-mode

Can anybody help me write this in latex? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\dot{\overline{\int_{\mathcal{P}_t} \rho\,dv}} = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To adjust the limits as the OP showed, per egreg's reminder, use `\limits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\dot{\overline{\int\limits_{\mathcal{P}_t} \rho\,dv}} = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\int\limits` would give the same picture as in the OP's question.

Comment: Steven, many thanks for being so kind helping me. It took me a long while and I got nowhere! It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Ingrid You are welcome.  If this answer provides exactly what you need, consider clicking the up arrow to the left of the *one* answer (if there are more than one answer) that best answers the question.  That is called "accepting" the answer and tells other readers what you found most helpful.